# Unable to Remove Google Drive PDF Preview Icon on Embedded Content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, iframe, embedded-resource

When I embed a PDF from Google Drive on my website, I encounter a persistent issue where a preview icon appears in the top right corner of the embedded PDF. Despite my attempts to remove or disable it using common methods, the preview icon continues to be displayed.

I though about putting a div on it to hide it from getting accessible, although it does not convince me enough.

Comment: @KJ As far as I understand you, there is no way to make the preview option inaccessible, other then blocking it by an other object with higher z-index.